# Error in XSLT-An attribute node cannot be created after the children of the containing element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple XML file for which I need to do some modifications in current XML.Basically I want to change the structure of XML. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong or suggest an alternative approach?

Input XML

```
       <CollectionDetails>
        <CollectionDetail AmountCollected="10.00">
            <PaymentMethod PaymentType="VISA"/>
        </CollectionDetail>
        <CollectionDetail AmountCollected="10.00">
            <PaymentMethod PaymentType="CREDIT">
   <PersonInfoBillTo AddressLine1="2308 SE 28th St" AddressLine2="address" 
   />
        </CollectionDetail>
        </CollectionDetails>
```

XSTL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
<xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="Pid" match="PaymentMethod" use="@PaymentType" />
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CollectionDetail">
    <xsl:copy-of select="PaymentMethod[count(key('Pid',@PaymentType)[1]|.)=1]" />
    <xsl:attribute name="AmountCollected">
        <xsl:value-of select="CollectionDetail/@AmountCollected" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
  <CollectionDetails>
        <PaymentMethod AmountCollected="10"
        PaymentType="VISA"/>
        <PaymentMethod AmountCollected="10" PaymentType="CREDIT">
           <PersonInfoBillTo AddressLine1="2308 SE 28th St" 
  AddressLine2="address" 
   /></PaymentMethod>
    </CollectionDetails>
```

Comment: I don't understand the code, you declare a key `<xsl:key name="Pid" match="CollectionDetail" use="@PaymentType" />` for the `CollectionDetail` elements which in your sample input don't have any `PaymentType` attribute at all.

Comment: @MartinHonnen corrected the XSLT

Comment: If you want to "add" an attribute to the `PaymentMethod` elements you certainly can't make an `xsl:copy-of` of them, rather write a template matching them and (I guess) add/pull in the attribute from the parent element inside of an `xsl:copy` or a literal result element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you show me any sample ?

Comment: The easiest is `<xsl:template match="PaymentMethod"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@* | ../@AmountCollected"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` and to skip the parent with `<xsl:template match="CollectionDetail"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`. I still haven't figured what you need the key for, the sample data doesn't seem to have any duplicates or cross references.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question instead. You too, @MartinHonnen.